# Formula to return second to last number in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula:

```
=INDEX(K14:V14,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,K14:V14))
```

which provides a result of the last numerical data point in a column range. However I am looking also to have a formula that reports back the second to last data point.

Answer (score 3):

Although I prefer the more succinct `1E+99` your original formula is perfect to find the last number in a row. You just need to reshape the range used by the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to one column less than the last number using an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with a similar MATCH function limiting the columns to look at.

[image: Second to last number in row]

The formula in K12 is,

```
=INDEX(K14:V14, MATCH(1E+99, K14:INDEX(K14:V14, MATCH(1E+99, K14:V14)-1)))
```

This can also be performed with the newer [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) if you value keeping up with the trends.

```
=INDEX(K$14:V$14, AGGREGATE(14, 6, COLUMN($1:$12)/SIGN(LEN(K$14:V$14)), 2))
```

There are 12 columns in the K14:V14 range. By forcing any column with a blank to a `#DIV/0!` error (and ignoring errors with the 6 as the *option* parameter) we can retrieve the second (the 2 in the *k* parameter) last number.

The advamtage of this style of formula is that AGGREAGATE's 14 sub-function mimics the standard worksheet [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db). Replace the 2 with ROW(1:1) and fill down and you return a series of non-blank numbers working from right-to-left. (see w10:W13 in the sample image).

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: You should change your references to column L; they should instead be references to column K, just in case the last cell with a number is K14.

Comment: Point taken but this formula really needs an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) as a wrapper. There is so much that can go wrong if not enough numbers are there to fulfill the 'second-to-last-number' requirement. I left it out as the OP seemed to be operating without training wheels.

Comment: Great formula. +1. How was SIGN(LEN(K$14:V$14) working in this please? This to do with the div/0 production?

Comment: @QHarr, yes you don't want to divide by anything but one or zero. The length of a blank is of course zero and SIGN changes any other positive integer to a one.

Answer (score 2):

This formula will return the second to the last data point:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/K14:INDEX(K14:V14,MATCH(1E+99,K14:V14)-1),K14)
```

Comment: It works as long as there is at least one number in the range. :)